# How do I power an Information Panel?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I've been using Tekkit quite a bit and I love it! However, I've stumbled onto a conundrum. I have a number of IC2 Industrial Information Panels and I need to power them. Sounds really simple right? But I can't get it to work:

I can run red alloy cable out of the back, but I can't connect red alloy cable to a BatBox, MFSU or any other power box I seem to have.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=5915), the Industrial Information Panel is powered by a redstone signal, such as a redstone torch or switch.

Answer (score 0):

Red alloy wire is not compatible with the IC2 add-on. It needs a vanilla redstone wire. EDIT: Tekkit has been updated and IC2 is now compatible with RP

Comment: I don't think that is true. My Information Panels are wired with red alloy wire?